# sshpass command not found when I run it in java

Tags: java, bash, shell, sh, sshpass

I am trying to run a command to read a string from a file inside a remote address (and I'm sure the file is there), this command works when I run it on the bash but it doesn't work when I run it in my java code.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] command;
    String line;

    try {
        command = new String[] {"sh", "-c", "\"sshpass " + "-p " + password + " ssh " + user + "@" + ip + " 'cat " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'\"" };

        Process mountProcess = rt.exec(command);

        mountProcess.waitFor();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mountProcess.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            user_list.put(user, line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mountProcess.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Stderr: " + line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch ...
```

No line is added to my user_list (so the line from getInputStream is null) and I get the following error from the logger in the code:

```
Stderr: sh: 1: sshpass: not found
```

If I use the exact same command on the bash it works and it prints the string I need.

```
sshpass -p password ssh remote@192.168.1.10 'cat /home/ID/ID'
```

Anyone knows why this is happening? thanks!

Comment: give full path of `sshpass`

Comment: Consider formatting the string for command
https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0463.html

Comment: I tried with the full path "/usr/local/bin/sshpass" instead of just "sshpass" and I still have the same error

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you don't need to use `sh` to wrap your command. Try

```
command = new String[] {"sshpass", "-p", password, "ssh", user + "@" + ip, "cat " + file.getAbsolutePath() };
```

---

If you need to use `sh`, then remove the escaped double quotes from the command string: you are sending those as literal characters:

```
command = new String[] {
    "sh", 
    "-c", 
    String.format("sshpass -p %s ssh %s@%s 'cat %s'", password, user, ip, file.getAbsolutionPath())
};
```

If you're *still* getting "command not found", then you need to either specify the full path to `sshpass`, or ensure that its directory is in your PATH.

Comment: At first, I was trying this approach but it raises an exception if I don't use "sh" "-c"

Comment: I already tried your suggestion.
Without the double quotes, I get the following error message:


`Stderr: Could not create directory '/usr/share/tomcat8/.ssh'.`


Using the double quotes, with String.format exactly as you described:


`Stderr: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password /usr/bin/ssh remote@192.168.1.10 'cat /home/ID/ID': not found`

Answer (score 0):

When doing this command with java the user is tomcat8 instead of root (when used in the bash terminal)

The solution that worked for me included some flags:

```
String.format("/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p %s /usr/bin/ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s@%s 'cat %s'", password, user, ip, file.getAbsolutePath());
```